# Is it possible to get similar feature to Warmage Edge without becoming a Warmage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I am levelling up an sorcerer npc, that accompanies PCs. He focuses on the use of fire magic.

I really enjoyed Warmage Edge class feature and I wonder, if there is some similar feature, that may be obtained by a feat or magic item, but would be charisma based and would affect more than "only warmage spells". I was hoping I could find something in Complete Arcane or Divine, but sadly there was nothing.

> **Warmage Edge (Ex):** A warmage is specialized in dealing damage with his spells. Whenever a warmage casts a spell that deals hit point damage, he adds his Intelligence bonus (if any) to the amount of damage dealt. For instance, if a 1st-level warmage with 17 Intelligence casts magic missile, he deals
>   1d4+1 points of damage normally, plus an extra 3 points of damage due to his Intelligence bonus. The bonus from the warmage edge special ability applies only to spells that he casts as a warmage, not to those he might have by virtue of levels in another class.
>
> A single spell can never gain this extra damage more than once per casting. For instance, a fireball deals the extra damage to all creatures in the area it affects. However, if a 3rd-level warmage casts magic missile and produces two missiles, only one of them (of the warmage's choice) gains the extra damage, even if both missiles are directed at the same target. If a spell deals damage for more than 1 round, it deals this extra damage in each round.

3.0, 3.5, Dugeon Adventures and Dragon Magazines allowed.

Comment: To clarify - you want to add an ability score modifier to your fire spells' damage? Would you be okay with other ways of boosting damage?

Comment: I'm not aware of any existing mechanic, but it would certainly be possible to use the existing rules to extrapolate such an item or spell. After all, if a monk's belt can grant monk class features to non-monks, then a similar item should be able to grant a warmage's edge class feature to a non warmage.

Comment: @nijineko Whether or not that's a good idea is another story - the Monk's Belt is stronger on non-Monk characters who can afford to boost Wisdom more than a Monk can, and the same could be true of a Warmage Edge based item.

Comment: Quite true. I was not addressing any balance issues, only providing a congruent mechanic that accomplished a similar thing as the question requested. There are feats which accomplish a similar mechanic as duplicating a class feature as well, but I'm AFB, so that was the simplest well known example.

Comment: @nijineko Note, that the question is not exactly about Warmage Edge, but a similar ability, that would work with all sorcerer spells (not only Warmage's ones) and will be charisma based.

Comment: @SPavel if it would work similarly, then sure.

Comment: @momonga-sama I understand that. My point was more to the effect that there are items and feats (and a few spells now that I think of it) which provide the effect of access to a class feature ability. Such things could serve as a template for you to use item creation or spell research rules to get what you want. Note, there are also effects which switch the keyed stat as well. Might be a bit expensive to develop/craft, but it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no existing pre-made effect that will accomplish both the granting of that class feature and switch the keyed stat.

However, there are rules for creating new content built into the game. As such, you can work with your DM and create exactly such an item. For example, there are items, feats, spells, and powers which DO grant access to a class feature (just not the one you want), and there are also methods of switching the keyed stats (usually via a feat). Therefore, find an in-game example of each: a warmage, an effect which grants a class feature (such as a Monk's belt), and an effect which switches the key stat (preferably an effect which specifically switches the key stat from the warmage primary stat to your desired stat) in the game world, and use the item creation rules and or spell/power research rules in conjunction with the example(s) as a template to craft/develop what you want.

Might be pricey, but then you also have the advantage of DM approval built into the process. Also, some people have issues with the Monk's Belt, considering it to be an unbalancing effect as it can be used to grant, among other things, a boost to AC beneficial for any WIS focused character.

This also gives you a great excuse to go on a quest in your game to collect all the things (people in some cases) you'll need.

Comment: This is a very poor answer. You don't use any specific information. At first you say, that it's not possible and later you note otherwise...

Comment: @Momonga-sama The answer to your question "is there such an item or feat that will do 'x' thing" is NO. However, there are also rules for making your own stuff up, which I also mentioned for your benefit, same as my comments. So while there is no existing item/feat (hence the no answer) there are rules that will let you make said item/spell/power. Very different things.

Comment: @Momonga-sama please note that at no time did I say it was not possible. I said that the answer to you question is 'no', which is not the same thing as saying it's not possible.

Comment: Most users on this site do not need to be reminded that the DM *can* create anything he wants. That answer is rarely helpful. I don’t think it is here. The answer *no* is useful, but only if you can indicate how you came to that answer—say, what books or other resources have you searched in?

Comment: Again, that is not what I said. The item creation rules and the spell research rules are for the PLAYERS to create what they want. I never once said "the DM can create anything they want". As a bonus for using the rules (which mention working with your DM, btw) the approval is built in. Please stop misquoting me. The rules are in the DMG, the MIC, and the RC. Oh, and A&EG.

Comment: It is good answer. Better than "no, there is no item or feat in official books or Dragon magazine that grants such feature". nijineko answer contains that, and also points out possibility for PC to create such item. It's not about Deus ex machina DM homebrew item/feat.

Comment: @KRyan I almost forgot about your comment on this. ^^ While somewhat peeved in tone (apologies offered), I hope my previous comment-response answered. I will add that I also searched through my extensive 3.x collection as well as researched online sources.